# linked list not stored correctly, prints all nodes the same

Tags: c

i am having trouble with this problem i can not find the bug
i am storing strings form a file to a linked list. 
lets say the file contains 5 strings

1. jack
2. juan
3. steven
4. mike
5. sam

---

the problem is that when i print the 5 node's linked list
it prints  [sam] [sam] [sam] [sam] [sam] .
it prints the last string in all nodes 
i am confused

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct Node {
  char * data;
  struct Node *next;
};

struct Node *head;

void print() {
    while (head != NULL) {
        printf(" [%s] ", head->data);
        head = head->next;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

void insertb(char *data) {
   struct Node *temp;

   temp = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
   temp->next = NULL;
   temp->data = data;

   if (head == NULL) {
       head = temp;
       printf("%s\n", head->data);
   } else {
       temp->next = head;
       head = temp;
       printf("%s %s\n", temp->data, temp->next->data);
   }
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    head = NULL;

    char data[10];
    //int data;
    while (fscanf(file, "%s",&data) != EOF) {
        insertb(data);
        // printf("%s\n", data);
    }

    print();

    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the printf statments in the insertb function are just me trying to figure out what was being stored in the linked list IGNORE!!

Comment: you keep inserting the same buffer. that's why

Comment: have a look at `strdup`.

Comment: Also: your `print` function changes the value of `head`, so once you've printed the list, you only have the last element of the list and have leaked everything else...

Answer (score 1):

You have only a single buffer to store your strings, `data`.  Its contents get overwritten with every call to fscanf.

Try `insertb(strdup(data));`.

Answer (score 0):

you are setting the head to temp, which is the very last one every time you add some stuff into the list. In insertb function the else block is probably where you want to look for. Also it is considered to be a pretty bad idea to make global variables, hence it is very likely to change the content of the global variable, unintentionally and that can screw things over. I suggest you to look for pass by reference stuff in C also. I see that the other answer tells you to use strdup, maybe I am wrong too and I don't want to argue with that, but strdup duplicates the string. Instead of that I'd "re-initialize" the char array with

```
memset(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
```

and put manually a "\0" char at the end of the string to prevent saving rubbish in the buffer. Hope this helps.